# Why would this section of python code hang during execution?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, urllib2

```
try:
    html = urlopen('http://glbse.com/api/asset/' + asset.name)
except:
    print 'error while updating the price of ' + asset.name
    continue
json_txt = html.read()
ticker = json.loads(json_txt)
average_price = int(ticker['t24havg'])
if average_price == 0:
    average_price = int(ticker['t5davg'])
if average_price == 0:
    average_price = int(ticker['t7davg'])
if average_price == 0:
    average_price = int(ticker['latest_trade'])
if average_price == 0:
    print 'could not determine the price of ' + asset.name
    continue
asset.average_price = average_price
```

I am using mechanize for urlopen.
This code (and the rest of the program) seems to run fine for hours but, after having looped through this section thousands of times, will eventually hang  somewhere in this section of code.

It hangs for an indefinite length of time. I've even come back to it to find it had hung there for hours.

Googling the issue all I come up with are reports of a similar issue, where execution hangs on .read() which is reported to be fixed years ago.

So what is causing execution to hang and how can I fix or workaround it?

Comment: I've seen `json.loads` hang when not given a valid json file.  Are you sure you're always passing a proper json file?

Comment: Don't use a bare except `except:`; it'll catch _any_ exception. Catch only what you need to catch. Add some logging; that should help you discover what the problem is.

Comment: You could try passing the optional timeout argument to urllib2.urlopen and see if that helps.

Comment: @MRAB -- Including a KeyboardInterrupt (which is easy to send and the traceback would tell you exactly where the code was hanging).

Comment: @MRAB the thing is, from what I can tell, it's not catching any exception because if there were an exception, it would go onto the next asset and this issue would not present itself.

Comment: @Darthfett I will write something up to ensure passing of proper json and report back when I get new information.

Comment: Run it in `pdb` and step through line by line until it hangs.

Comment: @Daenyth I'm not sure that is a viable option as it sometimes takes hours for the issue to present itself while running without stopping at every line :/

Comment: using mechanize.Browser().open() instead of urlopen reveals a "urllib2.URLError urlopen connection time out" which is not raised when using urlopen alone. I strongly suspect this is the problem and my solution is to use mechanize.Browser().open() in place of urlopen in all cases.

Comment: @smickles You should answer your own question so it no longer appears in the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `mechanize.Browser().open()` instead of `urlopen` reveals a "`urllib2.URLError urlopen connection time out`" which is not raised when using `urlopen` alone. I strongly suspect this is the problem and my solution is to use `mechanize.Browser().open()` in place of `urlopen` in all cases